# Make a vector from a matrix in R

Tags: r

I make a vector V of length 9 from a matrix A or order 3*3 using its elements row wise. The code i tried.

```
A<-matrix(1:9,3,3)
V<-c(A[1,],A[2,],A[,3])
```

But I want to generalized it using loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
as.vector(t(A))
```

just transpose the matrix and convert to vector. Simple.